# Non-Biodegradable Glitter

Tags: plastic, non-bio-degradable

How can I dispose of a box full of non-biodegradable glitter in an ecologically friendly way? Everything i read about melting or burning plastic gives me conflicting information about toxins and i don't want to just throw it in the bin so the tiny pieces end up in our ground/food chain/water.

Answer (score 1):

Here in New Zealand we are lucky enough to have a weekly recycling collection, and need only leave our plastics and other recyclables at the kerb once per week. Though I accept we are perhaps luckier than most. I cannot know what country you are in but would encourage you to check the internet or local telephone directory for a plastics recycler or recycling depot in your area. Small pieces of plastic are seriously affecting our environment and wildlife. It is essential we stop this madness, and the solution rests with all of us doing our part.